# What wire should I use to replace URD in underground conduit

Tags: electrical, usa

I have a detached garage, about 80 feet away with a roughly 1" conduit, maybe 2", would have to measure, with an LB on the garage and house straight from ground. Knowing where this is going?

Was wired pre-2008, so the wire now its 2-2-4 URD. It comes straight into the basement and runs along various beams and into the panel. Subsequently in the garage it runs the 3 feet up the wall into the panel. The PVC pipe also shares a fiber optic cable, so running it straight into the panel is not going to do it.

So I been told and confirmed that running URD cable inside is a no-no since it is not rated for that. However, keep getting different reactions as to what I do. URD is supposed to be terminated completely outside in a large junction box, well I don't have one of those today.  SER cable is not rated for underground even in conduit.

So what can I really do? I am replacing the main panel, which is already over budget and unplanned for it. So really buying about 100 feet of cable, even aluminum is a sucker punch too.

Comment: Does the cable ever exit the PVC conduit run? Or does the PVC just terminate in a bell or blunt end and dump the URD out into your wall without any protection?

Comment: No protection. The URD comes into the basement via the LB where the hoe was drilled. from there it runs along the basement rafters about 20 feet to the main panel. Inside the garage it comes in from the wall though the lb, and stright into the panel. ONce inside either buildings, there is no more PVC.

Comment: How much power do you actually need at the garage?

Comment: The garage is wired for 100A service, and has a welder, car lift, Large air compressor, etc. So downsizing to a single 120V circuit will not cut it. It is  a 4-bay garage.

Comment: Can you get us the exact diameter of the conduit, then?  Also, is it possible to curtail some of the heavier equipment at the garage in conjunction with a temporary repair to the situation until you can fix this fully?

Comment: It is a 2" PVC pipe. I work from home, so cannot curtail usuage. Problem is the main panel has to be replaced as it has rusted. Due to the size and shere number of breakers, with the latest AFCI/GFCI standards for everything, the panel is setting me back about $2k in breakers alone.  They claim once they replace the main panel, everyting has to been NEC 2020 standards. Each electrician i met wants $1200 to do the  panel work and $4k to "retro fit" this wiring. Frankly i just don't got it, so something has to give somewheres, very frustrating.

Comment: What’s the sucker punch with aluminum ?  Usually upgrading to a larger service current code is required, why do you think 100 amp is not enough do you plan on welding while the car is charging? We don’t just add breakers to determine the size.

Comment: I assumed that colorful statement to be about current material cost.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance,but what exactly does "LB" stand for?

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-3-4-in-Gray-Schedule-40-and-80-PVC-Type-LB-Conduit-Body-E986E-CTN/100404084

Answer (score 2):

### Whoa, whoa, whoa.  Get a restraining order against the "scope creep".

Who may just be your electrician "padding the bill".

The Grandfathering rule is very simple: **if it was legal on the date it was installed, *it's legal now***.

So the 3-wire subpanel feeder is legal now.

AFCI/GFCI requirements apply to *circuits* not to breaker panels.  Since you are not changing the rest of the circuit, the new breakers are not required.

And that makes a lot of sense when you think about it.  If someone finds an FPE panel, we want them to replace it, not encounter an ever-increasing scope of work bringing more and more stuff up to 2017 Code to the point where they say "frack it, I can't afford to replace the FPE!"
*That would be a bad outcome, **which is WHY** you don't have to replace every darn thing when you replace a panel from rust*.

Replacing a panel is JUST replacing a panel.

### The URD

It is correct URD isn't allowed outdoors in conduit (which is presumed to be 100% full of water 100% of the time).

However read ALL the cable types marked on the cable - often cables are a list of several types all at once, and if ONE of them is allowed in your usage, you're all set.

In fact, there's about a foot of writing on the side of the URD wires.  We need to see what those markings are, exactly, letter for letter, all of them, every one.  And then we can tell you if this cable is URD *and something else that is legal*. Which is what I suspect.

Lastly, you have a compressor and a car lift. So you're handy. What would it take for YOU to run a conduit from the panel to within 1’ of where the existing conduit comes into the house now? Properly with sweeps, LBs fully accessible, whole nine yards.  And with forward thinking so that on changeover day, you can just install the last 1’ of conduit and have a complete run.  My proposal is:

- Run conduit from panel to entry point *at your leisure*.  Use EMT because it's an "Erector Set", easy to unscrew and rearrange if you make a mistake.
- On changeover day, yank the bad old wires out.
- Connect that final 1’ of conduit.
- pull the new XHHW wires in.

If you can get a viable conduit route built, the actual wire swap is easy work for an electrician. As long as you stay smart with using aluminum wire, honestly, the wire will be cheaper than the Polaris connectors you'd need for a splice. We're talking under $100 of wire for #2.

- #2Al gets you 90A (yeah really, the last guy blew it)
- #1Al gets you 100A (if you like round numbers)
- #1/0 Al gets you 120A (breaker at 125A)

The fiber can stay in the conduit but will need to come out a "tee" conduit body, so may need to be pulled out and pulled back in with the feeder.

Answer (score 0):

### First problem: the flappy wires

The first, and most pressing, problem with this installation is the multiplex cable floating loose in the walls.  This needs to be corrected before we do anything about any other problem with this run; fortunately, since the rest of the run was done in PVC, it should be fairly simple to fix this up. You'll need a [25' coil of 2" ENT](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-2-in-x-25-ft-Electrical-Nonmetallic-Tubing-Conduit-Coil-Blue-12011-25/207160084) (or perhaps two of them depending on how long the runs are), a couple of 2" PVC T bodies with bell-ends on their side ports to let the fiber exit, a 2" PVC LL body to make the bend at the main panel, and a couple of 2" PVC male adapters.  After the existing wires are removed and replaced with an overlength pull string, the existing bell ends (if present) on the PVC conduit run are cut off and replaced with T bodies with bell ends on their side ports.  Then, the LL can be fitted in place of the existing cableclamp at the panel, and the ENT runs installed to complete the conduit panel-to-panel.

### Second problem: underwhelming cable selection

The issue with the existing wire is twofold; not only does it lack a separate grounding wire, it is one size too small for use at 100A as the NEC 310.15(B)(7) "83% rule" for dwelling units doesn't apply to a feeder to an outbuilding in most cases.  As a result, we'll need to swap that 100A breaker for a 90A breaker, even if you don't change anything else about the setup.

As to replacing the cable, though, the cheapest solution would be a length of [2-2-4-6 mobile home feeder cable](https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/2-2-4-6-aluminum-mobile-home-feeder-cable).  This keeps you at 90A and saves you a bit of money with an undersized neutral, but gets you your ground wire while being allowed in conduit both indoors and out.  You could use a larger cable given that you have plenty of conduit area to do so, but taking advantage of that would require an upgrade to the panel in the garage, so that can be saved for later.

### As to that other conduit run...

You can use a similar strategy for the other conduit run if you wish to, or since it's a smaller conduit, you can use an appropriate NM cable for the indoor runs with junction boxes for the transitions instead.  You could even pull a 12/3 UF cable through the conduit, running from panel to panel, with a 20A breaker at the headend and a 60A minimum disconnect at the shed as per NEC 225.39.  Note that the UF cable would be a much trickier pull than either of the other two approaches, though.

Comment: What cable would I use for the shed to keep it rated for 50A? 6/3 UF?

Comment: @user2213594 -- 6/3 UF won't come close to fitting in the conduit for the shed, nor will a 2-2-4-6 MHF cable.  You'll need to use individual 6AWG Cu THHN or 4AWG Al XHHW-2 wires with a 10AWG copper ground for that run if you want 50-60A from it.